# Timed interval always evaluates to zero

Tags: c++, c, timer, opencl

The code on the host is like this:

```
#include<time.h>
clock_t start,finish;
start=clock();
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(.........);
finish=clock();
double time = (double)(finish-start)/(double)(CLOCK_PER_SEC);
```

Why is finish - start always 0? Is it because of low resolution, or is there something wrong with my timer code?

Comment: you question should be why `finish` == `start` ?

Comment: Make some more calls to your kernel like 100 to 10000 and try again if it was for low resolution.

Comment: Maybe ((double)(finish-start))/((double)(CLOCK_PER_SEC));  ?

Comment: yes, it seems start==finish. EnqueueNDRangeKernel() does not cost time? But it should cost time.

Comment: "no time in clock" isn't the same as "took no time at all". If you have a watch that only ticks once a minute, it wouldn't be very useful to measure a 100m running competition, because everyone will be 0 minutes - but it didn't mean they took zero time to get there. `clock`'s tickfrequenecy is often 1ms or 10ms, so if the time it takes isn't long enough to "tick" one tick, then you get zero.

Answer (score 3):

Enqueue-ing a kernel is very cheap, since the function call can return before the kernel is executed.

You could use the event generated by the **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel** to **clWaitForEvents** until the kernel is actually executed.

Answer (score 2):

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel only queues the kernel up to run.  Unlike traditional C code that most folks are used to when debugging, OpenCL is not a serial process.  To force your code to act in a serial manner you can either make them blocking (when available, see clEnqueueWriteBuffer and clEnqueueReadBuffer) or throw a clFinish() after each OpenCL command that uses a cl_command_queue.  clFinish() forces all commands in the cl_command_queue to finish.

This allows you to use host timers easily.

Others have mentioned profiling events which are the intended method for profiling OpenCL calls.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already inferred, if you are using an unblocking clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (which is not explicit in your code), you are not measuring the kernel execution time because the enqueueing function returns without any guarantee that the kernel as finished execution (or even started it). 
You can pass a reference to a profiling event to the enqueue method and then inquire it about start and ending times. Using the cpp wrapper:

```
cl::Event timingEvent;
queue_0.enqueueNDRangeKernel(mx_kernel,cl::NullRange,global,local,NULL,&timingEvent);
queue_0.finish();//wait for kernel to be executed
timingEvent.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,&start_time);
timingEvent.getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,&end_time);
unsigned long elapsed = (unsigned long)(end_time - start_time);
```

For this to work you have to enable profiling in your queue upon object construction:

```
cl::CommandQueue queue_0 = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[0], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);
```