# How to timer the NVIDIA SDK examples?

Tags: sdk, opencl, nvidia

I tried to timer the oclVectorAdd example. I use clGetProfilingInfo, the GPU timer to record the time spent on kernel execution. Time is caculated in milliseconds. But the output is weird.
code and output are below:

```
    cl_ulong start,end;
cl_event event_ker_x;
ciErr1 = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cqCommandQueue, ckKernel, 1, NULL, &szGlobalWorkSize, &szLocalWorkSize, 0, NULL, &event_ker_x);
shrLog("clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (VectorAdd)...\n");
if (ciErr1 != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    shrLog("Error in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, Line %u in file %s !!!\n\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
    Cleanup(argc, argv, EXIT_FAILURE);
}
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event_ker_x, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event_ker_x, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &end, NULL);
float ker_x_time= (end-start) * 1.0e-6f;
shrLog("kernel execution time is : %f\n", ker_x_time);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (VectorAdd)...
kernel execution time is : 18446744027136.000000
clEnqueueReadBuffer (Dst)...
```

Comment: Maybe I need add clWaitForEvents() before retrieve the profiling info , right?

Comment: Looks like you have the same problem as this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794353/timed-interval-always-evaluates-to-zero

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a similar problem as this person: [Timed interval always evaluates to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794353/timed-interval-always-evaluates-to-zero)

In OpenCL, `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` queues up the kernel to run but doesn't necessarily execute the kernel right away.  To profile your kernel with events, try checking the execution time after the `clEnqueueReadBuffer` or add a `clFinish(..)` after the `clEnqueueNDKernelRange`.

Comment: thx. I have got the way about dealing with the kernel time. But could you tell me how to record the total execution time? I wish to use clGetEventProfilingInfo as well because it seems it is the highest resolution we can get.

Comment: Add clFinish() after clEnqueuNDKernelRange()

Comment: eh..I mean the total program execution time ,not only kernel execution time.thx

Comment: See the other thread, you can either use host timers and clFinish() or you can use profiling events for each OpenCL call and sum the times up.  Depends on what precision you need, host timer is usually good enough for my work.